# React sends last element in map when passing to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, event-handling

I am trying to create dynamic UI elements using react and have created a loop of elements by mapping over an array and on clicking the element, it passes the values to a function. My code looks something like below

```
const [shortlistedIds, setShortlistedIds] = useState([]);
const attachmentInputRef = useRef();

const handleOpenFilePicker = async () => {
  attachmentInputRef.current.click();
};

//somewhere in code, set the IDs
setShortlistedIds(["1", "2", "3", "4"]);

const handleFilePicker = async(e) => {
  console.log(e.target.id)
  let uploadFiles = [...e.target.files]
  const apiRes = await api.createAttachment(e.target.id, uploadFiles)
 }

return(
  {shortlistedIds.map((myId) => (
    <button
       id={myId}
       className="attachment-button pull-right"                 
       onClick={handleOpenFilePicker}
       style={{ position: "absolute" }}
    >
       click me {myId}
    </button>
    <input
        id={myId}
        ref={attachmentInputRef}
        type="file"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        name="file"
        onChange={(e) => {handleFilePickerChange(myId, e);}}
        multiple
     />

  )
)};
)
```

The html is rendered properly with correct id and text for each button but on clicking, the value printed in console from the handleFilePicker is always the last ID, "4" from above example, not matter which button I click. Not sure what the issue is here.
(please ignore any typos as this is an example code based on the actual code. It is not feasible to paste the actual code here)

Comment: What happens when you do this: onClick={handleFilePicker(myId)}

Comment: I need the the event details as the button opens up file picker but even if I do onClick = {(e) => {handleFilePicker(e, myId)}}, it still prints "4" to console.

Comment: onClick={(e) => this.handleFilePicker(myId, e)}: try this

Comment: There's no reason for `handleFilePicker` to be async. You're just returning a promise that you're doing nothing with. And set your state immediately with that array, otherwise you need to introduce `useEffect` to update it.

Comment: Just did. Didn't seem to make any difference. @vaira

Comment: @Andy, I'm doing a few API calls in handleFilePicker and thus need it to be async. This isn't in the code above as I didn't think it had anything to do with the question. I've updated the question to reflect this

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to be a [minimal, complete, and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. Please provide all relevant code in your question. I suspect the `style={{ position: "absolute" }}` has something to do with your issue since the buttons are likely "stacked" and the last button is the one on top of the "stack".

Comment: Hello @DrewReese, The code is too big and has too many complicated dependencies to be able to provide a complete working version. I've tried to provide a minimal example which should make it simple enough to understand. Also, i've tried removing the `style={{ position: "absolute" }}` part but that didn't seem to help. Also, the html elements are being rendered fine so I doubt it's a stacking issue.

Comment: We don't need to see *all* of your code, just enough of a complete code example that reproduces the issue you have with your code. The hopes are if you can reproduce the issue with minimal code we can resolve it and you can apply the solution against your *actual* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the above case is that the `useRef()` points to a reference and thus, reassigning it changes the value each time it is assigned in the map, finally assigning to the final value. The `useRef()` hook is not replicated with each assignment in the input field.

To solve this, I moved the input block to a child component which created a `useRef()` hook for each of the input fields and thus works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple

```
const [shortlistedIds, setShortlistedIds] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
setShortlistedIds(["1", "2", "3", "4"]);
}, [])
const targetClick = (e)=>{
console.log(e);
}


return (
       {
        shortlistedIds.map(myId => {
          return(<button onClick={() =>targetClick(myId)} key={myId}>click me{myId}</button>)
         
        })
      }
)
```

Comment: Hi @Anwar, I'm not sure how exactly this is different from my code. What I'm doing in similar to this and doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You have done so many stupid mistakes. 'shortlistedIds' in useState line and 'shortListedIds' in the map line is not the same. This is the only one I have shown you. But in your code, so many typo mistakes I can see

Comment: Hello @Anwar, Thanks for pointing this out. The typos in code came in due to having to write the code here again as I couldn't paste my original code completely. The original code itself is working fine except for the event listener which seems to be printing only the last id on the console.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass attribute key={myid} in your button element.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31858981)